# problem with svn and "?"

Tags: iphone, svn

I have problem with svn. a have copied a xib file and i have an ? point int my file ( the xib) and i can not commit this file.

thanks for your answer.

Comment: You mean, a "question mark" inside the file, or in the filename? Or some special character that gets rendered as a question mark? File status showing up as a question mark? Or something else entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add those files with ? mark by selecting and clicking add button

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the file to svn first and then you can commit it.

? indicates that the file is not added to the svn folder and is missing. So add it to the svn first using

```
svn add
```

and then commit

Comment: @Izan: In future accept the answers that helped you and were answered first.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update it at first and when commit it !!!

Answer (score 0):

First delete that file from svn.
Now, commit entire project.
Then add the file to the repository and commit entire project again.
I hope this will solve your problem.